# Creating a Link Server From SQL 2005 to Azure

Tags: sql-server-2005, azure

I have a SQL Server 2005. I am trying to create a linked server to Azure SQL.

I set it up and tested the connection says it succeeded. However running any queries against it yields this

> Enumerate columns failed for LinkedServer 'EBPCLOUD'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
>
> Cannot obtain the schema rowset "DBSCHEMA_COLUMNS" for OLE DB provider "SQL Server" for linked server "(null)". The provider supports the interface, but returns a failure code when it is used. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 7311)

The exact same queries work on a different box, albeit with a newer version of SQL Server.

Comment: So you can create the linked server to azure from a newer version of your on-premises SQL server? It used to be that azure only supported linked servers via ODBC provider, so you could try that option if you get stuck.

Comment: E.g. http://kbijayanta.azurewebsites.net/2014/03/creating-a-linked-server-to-windows-azure-sql-database/

Comment: Yes you are correct about the ODBC at least from the documentation i am reading. I guess I need to ask directly:  is it possible to install the correct drivers to create a Link Server to Azure from a SQL Server 2005 platform running in Windows Server 2003?

Comment: The box is in question is on Server 2003 which will not connect to Azure.

Comment: Are you creating the linked server via an ODBC connection? According to http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlcat/archive/2011/03/08/linked-servers-to-sql-azure.aspx, when creating the ODBC DSN to the Azure database  you use the SQL Native Client driver sqlncli10.dll so I see no reason why it shouldn't work. I suggest you update your question with more details of _exactly_ what you're doing and what problems you encounter. Don't put this info in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server 2005 will not connect to Azure, 2008 R2 or higher required.